# How to get string data in input button attribute jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am getting data from database and using each loop to append data to grdbody.

```
$.each(Data, function (i, v) {
    $("#grdbody").append('<tr/>').children('tr:last')
    .append("<td class='first style2'><label id='lblDesc" + i + "'>" + v.Purpose + "</label></td>")
    .append("<td><a href='#' " value=" + v.Purpose + " onclick='CallPurpose(this)'>Select</a></td>")
     });
```

It is showing correct string like "My name is" on lblDesc but when I pass the same `v.purpose` to function `CallPurpose()` it is just showing only "My" text before blankspace.

```
function CallPurpose(cntrl)
{
    var RptDesc = $(cntrl).attr("value");
    alert(RptDesc); 
}
```

It is just showing "My" only text before space. how it will show complete string?

Comment: @Satpal that is anchor not input button.

Comment: it can not be get by using .val().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `single quote` before and after value as follow mentioned. Your code work fine after this correction.

```
.append("<td><a href='#' " value='" + v.Purpose + "' onclick='CallPurpose(this)'>Select</a>
                                ^^^^             ^^^^
```

Comment: thanks alot Sadikhasan....yes i was missing the single quotes,now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have messed up the quotes:

```
.append("<td><a href='#' value='" + v.Purpose + "' onclick='CallPurpose(this)'>Select</a></td>")
//----------------------^ remove a double quote from here and add a single quote.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
$("#grdbody").append('<tr/>').children('tr:last').append("<td class='first style2'><label id='lblDesc'" + i + "'>" + v.Purpose + "</label></td>").append("<td><a href='#' value='" + v.Purpose + "' onclick='CallPurpose(this)'>Select</a></td>");
```

Comment: Sridhar thanks your code is correct.i was missing the single quotes actually.